# How to create a function swapping 2d array elements based on user input in C?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

For my sliding puzzle lab, i'm required to make a 4x4 tile game numbered 15-1 (0 being the blank space).Ive started to make progress with my code but i have no idea how to create my moveTile function. I assume it may be using pointers but I'm not sure how to code it. I also need to use a different function to determine if a move is valid. The move would only be valid if the tile the user selects is next to an empty tile (0). The goal is to have the entire array in ascending order (1-15). Any help is greatly appreciated. Bare with me my coding skills are still a little rough

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int row = 4; //global variables for row column size of board
const int col = 4;

//function prototypes
void startGame(void);
void endGame(void);
void displayGame(int arr [row][col]);
int is_move_valid(int tile);
int moveTile(int arry[][]);


/*int moveTile() //function to move tiles
{
    
}
*/


int main(void) {

    startGame(); //Prints game initialization message
   
    char a; //char variable for user to start game
    
    
    printf("Menu: [p]rint , [m]ove , [q]uit: \n"); //gives user options to start game, move piece, or quit
    scanf(" %c", &a);
         while (getchar() != 'q') { //loops the game unless user decides to quit
             if ( a =='p')
             {
                 int board [][4] = { {0, 15, 14, 13},
                                     {12, 11, 10, 9},
                                     {8, 7, 6, 5},
                                     {4, 3, 2, 1}};
                 displayGame(board);
             }
             
        
        

        printf("\nMenu: [p]rint , [m]ove , [q]uit:\n");
        }
        
    
    endGame();
    return 0;
}
void startGame() //game initialization function definition
{
    printf("Setting Up The Game\n");
}

void displayGame(int arr [row][col]){ //board display function
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<row; i++) { //creates row elements
        printf("\n"); //formatting into 4x4
        for (j=0; j<col; j++) { //creates column elements
            printf("%3d", arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
int is_move_valid(int tile)
{
    
}
void endGame(void) //game teardown
{
    printf("Ending the game\n");
}

int moveTile(int arry[][]){
    int t; // integer variable for tile the user wants to move
    printf("Which tile would you like to move? :\n ");
    scanf("%d", &t);
}
```

Comment: You need to find the square that contains a tile. Then you need to check whether it is next to a tile that is 0, keeping in mind that a tile can also be next to the edge of the grid. If a tile is next to a 0, you set that other square to the tile value, and the current square to 0. Break down the problem in smaller, very specific checks.

Comment: There are two ways to look at moves. One is, moving a specific numbered tile in a specific direction that points into the open space. Using this approach means that the selected tile needs to have the open space in the correct adjacent position, assuming that the adjacent position is on the board of course. This is rather complex. Another way of looking at it is, a move is just sliding a tile into the open space from a specific direction. You might find that latter approach to be more helpful, from a user interface point of view.

Comment: `int arry[][]`: this is invalid, you need to specify the second dimension, e.g `int arry[][4]`

Answer (score 0):

While you think of how to implemt the moves, let me point out that your design looks sort of inside-out; the big thing is going to be `playGame()`, so that would be the important function called by `main()`.

```
int main(void) {
    
    printf("Setting Up The Game\n");

    playGame(); 

    printf("Thank you for playing!\n");

}
```

Now you have a beginning, a middle, and an end. And don't need any comments so far.

If the start up or tear down need more, then you can put these lines also into  functions.

---

moves: the null tile can move like a rook in chess: 1 to max squares, but not diagonally; but the user probably does not want to move around the hole.